# Swift Block value error

Tags: swift, swift3

I keep getting a finish block error in swift. The error is:

> Cannot call value of non-function type'((Array,Array)->())!

There's an image of the error below as well. Here's the code:

```
var blockFinih: ((_ selectedTags: Array<Tag>, _ unSelectedTags: Array<Tag>) -> ())!

func finishTagController() {
    var selected: Array<Tag> = Array()
    var unSelected: Array<Tag> = Array()

    for currentTag in tags {
        if currentTag.isSelected {
            selected.append(currentTag)
        }
        else {
            unSelected.append(currentTag)
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        self.blockFinih(selectedTags: selected, unSelectedTags: unSelected)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the argument labels when you call `blockFinih`. You've defined it to have no argument labels. The parameters `selectedTags` and `unSelectedTags` can only be used inside the function, not by the caller.

Change:

```
self.blockFinih(selectedTags: selected, unSelectedTags: unSelected)
```

to:

```
self.blockFinih(selected, unSelected)
```